# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a List of Marker to add them on a map but I got my datas from an API and when I call this API my return type of my function is Future so it's normal. I use await on my Future list to cast it into a normal List but it doesn't work and i received this error :

type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List'

You can find my code here :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:companion/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:companion/utils/user_preferences.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MapMarker {
  final String? image;
  final String? title;
  final String? address;
  final LatLng? location;
  final int? rating;

  MapMarker({
    required this.image,
    required this.title,
    required this.address,
    required this.location,
    required this.rating
  });
}

getAllPlaces() async {
  User user = UserPreferences.user;

  Future<List> futureAllPlaces = callAPI(user);
  List allPlaces = await futureAllPlaces;

  List<MapMarker> urbexPlaces = [];
  for (var place in allPlaces) {
    urbexPlaces.add(
        MapMarker(
            image: 'image',
            title: place['urbexPlaceName'],
            address: 'address',
            location: LatLng(double.parse(place['urbexPlaceLatitude']), double.parse(place['urbexPlaceLongitude'])),
            rating: 5
        )
    );
  }
  print(urbexPlaces);

  return urbexPlaces;
}

Future<List> callAPI(User user) async {
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('api'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode({
      'apikey': 'dev',
      'action': 'LIST',
      'userToken': user.userToken,
      'language': 0
    }),
  );

  String responseBody = response.body;

  List allPlaces = [];
  allPlaces.addAll(json.decode(responseBody));

  return allPlaces;
}
final List mapMarkers = getAllPlaces();
```

I need my variable mapMarkers to be a list in order to use it in a loop

Comment: Try using FutureBuilder and create future for `getAllPlaces`

Answer (score 1):

`getAllPlaces` returns a `Future<List<MapMarker>>`. It would be better if you actually used that as an explicit return type, instead of relying on the compiler.

So you need to `await` that:

```
final List mapMarkers = await getAllPlaces();
```